# jquery add a fade to an .addClass

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, fading

How do I fade .addClass in and out.

Here is the link -

[http://www.bikramyogajoondalup.com.au/about-bikram-yoga/postures-benefits.html](http://www.aus-media.com/dev/site_BYJ/new-students/faqs_questions.html)

and here is the code -

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#menu li#Q_01,#menu li#Q_03,#menu li#Q_05,#menu li#Q_07,#menu li#Q_09,#menu li#Q_11,#menu li#Q_13').hover(function() {
    $(this).addClass('pretty-hover');
  }, function() {
    $(this).removeClass('pretty-hover');
  });
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#menu li#Q_02,#menu li#Q_04,#menu li#Q_06,#menu li#Q_08,#menu li#Q_10,#menu li#Q_12').hover(function() {
    $(this).addClass('pretty-hover_01');
  }, function() {
    $(this).removeClass('pretty-hover_01');
  });
});
```

Thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If jQuery UI is an option, you can use [`.toggleClass(class, duration)`](http://jqueryui.com/demos/toggleClass/) for this.

Also, you can probably simplify your selector, it looks like [`:even`](http://api.jquery.com/even-selector/) and [`:odd`](http://api.jquery.com/odd-selector/) will do the job based on your current selector, like this:

```
$(function() {
  $('#menu li:even').hover(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('pretty-hover', 500);
  });
  $('#menu li:odd').hover(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('pretty-hover_01', 500);
  });
});
```

I realize the above seems backwards, but `:even` does select the *first* element, because it's 0 based, so even selects 0th, 2nd, 4th, etc.  I hope you'll agree, makes it a bit easier to maintain :)

**Edit based on comments** - Since `.toggleclass()` sticks on quick hovers, here's an alternative that works as expected, just a bit longer:

```
$('#menu li.post:even').hover(function() {
  $(this).stop().animate({ backgroundColor: '#009FDD', color: '#FFF' }, 500);
}, function() {
  $(this).stop().animate({ backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF', color: '#666' }, 500);  
});
$('#menu li.post:odd').hover(function() {
  $(this).stop().animate({ backgroundColor: '#623A10', color: '#FFF' }, 500);
}, function() {
  $(this).stop().animate({ backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF', color: '#666' }, 500);  
});
```

Comment: I have implemented the code on a new page and it works well. I just have one problem.

When I hover over the list items quickly the fades dont complete and seem to get a bit stuck. Any ideas?

Comment: sorry the link is
http://www.aus-media.com/dev/site_BYJ/about-bikram-yoga/postures-benefits.html

Comment: @Nik - Not sure why toggleClass sticks like that, seems you're not the only one seeing this behavior though.  I updated the answer with an `.animate()` alternative that works as you'd expect, not too bad since you're only animating a few properties.

Comment: Mr Craver your a legend! When I can, I will surely score your advice. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to fade the colours of an element, you'll need to use [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/) which has more advanced support for fading and animating (the core jQuery can only fade/animate integer properties: colours don't work).

It even supports animating all the properties in [an entire CSS class](http://jqueryui.com/demos/addClass/), so using jQuery UI, you should be able to achieve the effect you want.

Comment: Thanks guys I will give the UI a go. The download package looks good!

Answer (score 0):

the jQuery [.animate](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) function is the best bet, although this won't let you animate between CSS classes - you have to specify the individual styles.

You would be better using the jQquery UI, as this would provide for this sort of functionality, as stated in the jQuery [animate](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) page:

> The [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/) project extends the
>   .animate() method by allowing some
>   non-numeric styles such as colors to
>   be animated. The project also includes
>   mechanisms for specifying animations
>   through CSS classes rather than
>   individual attributes